# How to bind linesements point to xml data in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some data

```
<Array>
    <Element Value="30"/>
    <Element Value="50"/>
    <Element Value="10"/>
</Array>
```

Now I want to create a curve using this data. I think to use the LineSegments. But I can't understand how to bind the LineSegment Points to this data?

I mean, is there any syntax that helps to write instead of

```
<GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
  <PathGeometry>
    <PathFigure>
      <LineSegment Point="0,30"/>
      <LineSegment Point="20,50"/>
      <LineSegment Point="40,10"/>
    </PathFigure>
  </PathGeometry>
</GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
```

something like this:

```
<GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
  <PathGeometry>
    <PathFigure>
      <LineSegment Point={Binding ????}/>
    </PathFigure>
  </PathGeometry>
</GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
```

The main problem is how to bind the coordinates to point structure of a linesegment using binding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where should the x values be coming from? I'd suggest creating a proper view model (google `MVVM`) that provides those LineSegments (or PointCollections for binding to Polyline elements).

Comment: x values is the constant step. For instance step = 2, so we need to build a curve with the following coordinates:

(0,30),
(2,50),
(4,20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of converting array of points into `LineSegment` collection, you can simply use `PolyLineSegment`. If the `Binding` just need to work intially (turn array of points to `PointCollection` of the `PolyLineSegment` intially, after that every changes made on the array of points won't trigger updating to the `PolyLineSegment`), you can do something like this:

```
public MainWindow(){
   InitializeComponent();
   //set DataContext
   //Initialize your Points here ...
   //...
   DataContext = this;       
} 
public Point[] Points {get;private set;}
```

Here is the converter used to convert the array of points to `PointCollection`:

```
public class PointArrayToPointCollection : IValueConverter {
   object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      var points = value as IEnumerable<Point>;
      if(points != null) return new PointCollection(points);
      return Binding.DoNothing;
   }
   object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Then in XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="yourNameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"            
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourNameSpace"/>
  <Window.Resources>
     <local:PointArrayToPointCollection x:Key="pointsToPointCollection"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Image>
     <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
           <DrawingImage.Drawing>
             <GeometryDrawing>
               <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                  <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"></Pen>
               </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
               <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                  <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure>
                       <PolyLineSegment Points="{Binding Points,
                          Converter={StaticResource pointsToPointCollection}}"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                  </PathGeometry>
               </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
             </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
     </Image.Source>
  </Image>
</Window>
```

This answer may not exactly solve your problem but the idea of using `PolyLineSegment` should point you to the right direction.

**Update**:

Well I just thought you need some actual code run in real application. If you need just XAML code to test (or play with) right in *KXAML* editor, there is no reason for you to use XML data here. Because we need exactly a `PointCollection` for the `Points` property of a `PolyLineSegment`, so using any other kind of data will require some conversion (which can be done only via code behind). So we can just need to specify the `PointCollection` as an instance right in XAML code, it can be like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <PointCollection x:Key="points">
     <Point>0,30</Point>
     <Point>20,50</Point>
     <Point>40,10</Point>
  </PointCollection>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>  
  <Grid.Background>
   <DrawingBrush>
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          <GeometryDrawing>
             <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"></Pen>
             </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
             <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <PathGeometry>
                   <PathFigure>
                       <PolyLineSegment Points="{StaticResource points}"></PolyLineSegment>
                   </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
             </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>
      </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

I understand that you may have a collection of more continuous points (which can shape a nearly curvy line). If you want some perfect curve, you can try playing with `BezierSegment`, `PolyBezierSegment`, `QuadraticBezierSegment`, `PolyQuadraticBezierSegment` like this:

```
<Grid>  
 <Grid.Background>
   <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" Viewport="0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6">
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          <GeometryDrawing>
             <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"></Pen>
             </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
             <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <PathGeometry>
                   <PathFigure>
                       <PolyBezierSegment Points="10,10 200,150 300,30 320,10 330,-100 20,30">
                       </PolyBezierSegment>
                   </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
             </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>
      </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
   </DrawingBrush>
 </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Or you can even try using the so-called mini Path language to define the PathGeometry like this:

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.Background>
   <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" Viewport="0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6">
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 C10,10 200,150 300,30 320,10 330,-100 20,30">
             <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"></Pen>
             </GeometryDrawing.Pen>                 
          </GeometryDrawing>
      </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
   </DrawingBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

The mini path language works due to the implicit `GeometryConverter`. You can use this mini language for `PathFigureCollection` (converted by `PathFigureCollectionConverter`) and the `Data` property of a `Path` shape.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any way to build the curve without usage of Converter? I need the curve to be built in KaXML program. So not sure that I can use any code behind the XAML.

Comment: @user1820318 see my update for more approaches. I would like to say that testing code right in KXAML is OK for some simple UI design, but it's not good for real application where you really need other features of Binding including `Converter`. You should try using ***Blend for Visual Studio***.